# If $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, is it possible to have $\sigma(b^2) \equiv b^2 \pmod 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisor-sum

The title says it all.

Let $\sigma(N)$ denote the *sum of the divisors* of the positive integer $N$.

To paraphrase my question:

> If $3 \mid \left(b^2 - 1\right)$, is it possible to have $3 \mid \left(\sigma(b^2) - b^2\right)$?

As a follow-up question:

> > If $X = \nu_{3}(b^2 - 1)$ and $Y = \nu_{3}(\sigma(b^2) - b^2)$, which of the following is true?
> >     $$X \leq Y$$
> >     or
> >     $$Y \leq X$$

**Update:** It turns out that, yes it is possible, and indeed *many* integers satisfy the conditions.  I am hoping somebody has some bright ideas on how to approach the second part of the problem.

Comment: Sure, take $b^2=4$. Or $b^2=1$. Or many many others.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading...if $b=2$ then $b^2=4\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  $\sigma (4)=7$ and so $\sigma(2^2)\equiv 2^2 \pmod 3$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Well, the fact is that $x^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$ if and only if $x$ is not a multiple of $3$. For instance, $b=5$ works, because $\sigma(25)=31$.

Comment: Okay, that covers all the cases then (i.e., $b$ odd and even).  If $b$ is an odd composite, can somebody comment on the second part of the question?

Comment: You should always work some examples first.   Why not answer the question yourself for the first few $b$?  Or even the first $100\;b$?

Comment: @lulu, agreed.  Doing so now.

Comment: Let's take primes $b>3$, due to Fermat's little theorem, $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. Then $\sigma(b^2)= 1 + b + b^2$ and $\sigma(b^2) - b^2 = b+1$. All the primes $b>3$ are either of $b=6q+1$ or $b=6q+5$ form. Obviously for those of form $b=6q+5$ we have $\sigma(b^2) - b^2 = b+1=6q+6$ which is divisible by 3. This is not true for the primes of $b=6q+1$ form. E.g. $b=7$.

Comment: Thanks, @rtybase!  Your comment adds perspective to the question.  Can you write that out as an actual answer please?  Thanks!

Comment: Done ... although incomplete ;)

Comment: That's fine.  I hope somebody here has something to say about the case when $b$ is an odd composite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer. Let's take primes $b>3$, due to Fermat's little theorem, $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. Then $\sigma(b^2)= 1 + b + b^2$ and $\sigma(b^2) - b^2 = b+1$. All the primes $b>3$ are either of $b=6q+1$ or $b=6q+5$ form. Obviously for those of form $b=6q+5$ we have $\sigma(b^2) - b^2 = b+1=6q+6$ which is divisible by 3. This is not true for the primes of $b=6q+1$ form. E.g. $b=7$ or $b=13$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $3 \mid (b^2 - 1)$ is equivalent to $3 \nmid b$ (as noted in the comments), then it appears (from a few quick computations for $b < 100$) that, for $3 \nmid b$:

> **(a)** If $3 \mid \left(\sigma(b^2) - b^2\right)$, then we have
>   $$\nu_{3}(b^2 - 1) = X = Y = \nu_{3}(\sigma(b^2) - b^2).$$
>   **(b)** If $3 \nmid \left(\sigma(b^2) - b^2\right)$, then we have
>   $$\nu_{3}(b^2 - 1) = X > Y = \nu_{3}(\sigma(b^2) - b^2).$$

So, it appears plausible that, in general, we have
$$\nu_{3}(b^2 - 1) = X \geq Y = \nu_{3}(\sigma(b^2) - b^2),$$
but I have no proof.

**Added June 2 2016** 
The difficulty in pursuing a proof for $Y \leq X$ lies in the obstruction of trying to rule out $0 < X < Y$.